# form not being loaded into template

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to implement my form in Django but it is not appearing. I checked the inspector on my browser and I do not see it at all meaning it is not being loaded.

If there is any other information needed. Let me know.

project structure:

```
/beerad
   urls.py
   /index
      views.py
      /templates
         /index
            index.html
   /templates
      /home
         home.html
      /navbar
         navbar.html
   /userapp
      forms.py
      views.py
      urls.py
```

userapp/forms.py:

```
class RegistrationFrom(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-username", "name": "username", "placeholder": "Username"}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-firstname", "name": "firstname", "placeholder": "First Name"}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"id": "signup-lastname", "name": "lastname", "placeholder": "Last Name"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"id": "signup-email", "name": "email", "placeholder": "Email"}))
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"id": "signup-password", "name": "password", "placeholder": "Password"}))
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"id": "signup-confirm-password", "name": "confirm-password", "placeholder": "Confirm Password"}))
```

index/templates/index/index.html:

```
{% extends "home/home.html" %}

{% block content %}


{% endblock %}
```

index/views.py

```
def load_index(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, "index/index.html")
```

templates/home/home.html

```
<body class="container">
{#{% block navbar %}{% endblock %}#}
{% include "navbar/navbar.html" %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% include "footer/footer.html" %}
{#{% block footer %}{% endblock %}#}
</body>
```

I tried using `{% blocks %}` but then my `navbar` does not appear anymore. It only appears when I use `include`

```
<body class="container">
{% include "navbar/navbar.html" %}

{% block content %}{% endblock %}

{% include "footer/footer.html" %}
</body>
```

beerad/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include("index.urls")),
    url(r'auth/', include("userapp.urls"))
)
```

userapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'signup/$', register),
    url(r'activation/$', activation)
)
```

userapp/views.py:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationFrom(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, "success.html", {"payload": request.POST})
        else:
            return render(request, "error/404.html")
    else:
        form = RegistrationFrom()
    return render(request, "navbar/navbar.html", {"form": form})
```

beerad/templates/navbar/navbar.html:

```
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="signup-pane">
      <form class="signup-form" method="post" action="/auth/signup/" id="create-account">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-xl" id="create-acc-btn" name="signup-submit">Create Account</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the block navbar in your home.html?

Comment: Is the code in your `navbar.html` template complete or do you maybe extend it from `home.html`?

Comment: @sthzg I did not extend it from `home.html`

Comment: Since your `register` view renders `navbar.html` directly I am a bit unsure why you've posted `home.html` as well. In this case it will never get triggered. Which view are you calling to test if the form gets rendered?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is entirely within the navbar block, but you've commented that out in your home template. So nothing in that block will appear.

Comment: Now you've edited the question to make my answer invalid. Please don't do that.